# Add New Line in textarea by getElementById().value not Working

Tags: javascript, textarea, newline

I'm quite new in Javascript. Sorry if I say some absurd. None of the previous answers I found here worked in my case...
The code gets an index from a selected option from a dropdown list generated by an array loop, and uses this index to post description of a product  in a textarea. Ideal would be one in each line. But whenever I add '\n'(added only for visualization by the end of the code)  or '&#10';  the dropdown list itself disapears. Trying '< br>' does not work either.

pr[] is a nested array that contains a description of 10 products (ex adidas soccer ball) in its first position and price at the second.

The function buy() is called by a button onclick event, each time it is called it adds one product to the textarea.
Thanks in advance!

```
textd=" ";
valord=0;
function buy() {
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var f =  e[0].selectedIndex; 
textd +=pr[f][0]; 
valore = valord += pr[f][1];
document.getElementById("compras").value=textd\n;
document.getElementById("valor").value ="R$ "+ valore+",00";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "\n" to the end of the string while adding text to text area, then this "\n" ensures that row will be displayed in a new line instead of same line.

Look at the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function appendText()
{
debugger;
var ele = document.getElementById("textArea");
var text = ele.value;
text += "im clicked\n";
text +="clicked again\n";
text +="clicked third time\n";
text +="clicked forth time";
ele.value = text;
}
</script>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">
At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
</textarea>

<button type="button" onclick="appendText()">Click me </button>
</body>
</html>
```

You may need to change your code to 
textd +=pr[f][0] + "\n"; 
document.getElementById("compras").value=textd;

Comment: Many, many thanks! Worked perfectly! Thanks a lot for your time and attention. Brgds from Rio de Janeiro! I have been using a lot the w3schools.com and I am really enjoying their material. Hope someday I got to the point to help others just like you did here.